# How to check if some number, say a, can be expressed as a = b + reverse(b) ? Where b is some natural number.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

How to check if some number, say $a$, can be expressed as $a = b + \mathrm{reverse}(b)$ ?  Where $a$ and $b$ are some natural numbers.

Some examples:

1. $22 = 11 + \mathrm{rev}(11) = 11 + 11$;  
   That is, $22$ can be expressed as sum of "another natural number and its reverse".
2. $121 = 29 + \mathrm{rev}(29) = 29 + 92$; 
   $9$ can't be expressed as sum of "a number and its reverse".

Comment: It's also not necessary, if we always assume that the reverse of a number takes its smallest decimal representation. e.g. 8 = 4 + rev(4).

Comment: @DonThousand Divisibility by $11$ only works if the number of digits in the seed number is even, or if the seed number is divisible by $11$. $123+321=444$.

Comment: @DonThousand It isn't a necessary condition. $444$ is not divisible by $11$

Comment: Check all natural numbers $0<b<a$ of which there are only a finite number of them.

Comment: Relevant [oeis](http://oeis.org/A067030)

Comment: The top voted answer takes two cases, when the first digit is 1 or the first digit and the last digit are equal and otherwise says the number cannot be expressed as sum of a number and it's reverse. The one case they leave out is when the carry from the second digit adds to the first and the first digit is 1 greater than the last. For example, 353 + rev(353) = 706, which op forgot to consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $b = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n b_k 10^k$

$b + rev(b) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}(b_k + b_{n-k})10^k < 2*10^{k+1}$.

Suppose $a$ is an $n+1$ digit number.

Case 1:  The first digit of $a$ is not equal to $1$.  Then if $a = b + rev(b)$ then $b$ is also an digit number and $b_0 + b_k < 10$.  So the first digit and last digit of $a$ are are $b_0 + b_k$ and equal.

If the first digit and last digit of $a$ are not equal then $a $ is not is not $b+ rev(b)$.  If the first digit and last digit or then remove the first digit and last digit, divide by $10$ and repeat the process.

Case 1a:  The first and last digit are $1$.  To see if $b_0 + b_k = 1$ and $a = b + rev(b)$, revert to case 1.  If it fails, continue to case 2.

Case 2:  The first digit of $a$ is $1$.  If $b_0 + b_k \ge 10+ $ last digit of $a = m$ and $a = b + rev (b)$ then subtract $m$ and $m*10^{n-1}$ from $a$. Divide by $10$. Repeat the process.

Either the process will end at a single digit and $a = b+ rev(b)$ or the process will fail and $a \ne b + rev (b)$ for any $b$.

Example:  $59406 + 60495=119901$ so

so subtract $100001$ to get $19900$ and divide by $10$ to get $1990$.  Subtract $10$ and $1000$ to get $980$ and divide by $10$ to get $98$ and that was a failure.

So go back to $119901$ and subtract $11$ and $110000$ so get $9890$ and divide by $10$ to get $989$.  Subtract $909$ and get $80$ and divid by $10$ to get $8$.  That's a success.